# write.table in a certain loop never releases memory

Tags: r, file-io

Consider these two pieces of code.  In the first one, things work normally, and the memory usage of R is stable:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
x <- rnorm(1000000)
write.table(x, file="test", col.names=F, append=T)
}
```

Now consider this related code, where I am scraping information from the World Bank about some economic indicator.  Here, the memory usage goes up as the loop is iterated:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
for (i in 1:26) {
x <- getURL(paste("http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO?per_page=500&date=1960:2012&page=", as.character(i), sep=""))
x <- xmlToDataFrame(x)
write.table(x, file="test", col.names=F, append=T)
}
```

What is the difference between these two snippets from the point of view of writing data, and how can I ensure that the second one releases memory properly?

Comment: My R is version 2.15 and my XML is version 3.9-4.1, which seem to be the most recent updates.

Comment: i've tried updating to XML version 3.93-0 via downloading the source code and using Rtools, but to no avail.  also downloading via the repository at omegahat.org doesn't work

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Are working on a 32bit or 64bit system?

Comment: i'm working on 64bit.  the linked stackoverflow page above mentions an updated binary for xml at omegahat, but this isn't available from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did this to make it work.  I downloaded the binary from http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/, and installed using install.packages("XML", repos=NULL).  It only worked in 32 bit R.